# Secure communication between server and application using AES (CBC) in Delphi7

Tags: delphi, security, delphi-7, aes, communication

I'm writing an application that will communicate to a php script (authentication.php?UserID=ClientsEmail@email.com&ClientsID=81E17) the script in return will notify the application if the client is found in the MySQL database and what files the client can download. All communication over the Internet will be AES-256 (CBC) encrypted and the main encryption key will be hard coded into the executable file. This main key will only be changed once a year by recompiling the exe and passing it as an upgrade to all clients. Because this key seldom changes it is crucial that I generate an initialization vector that hopefully never repeats itself.

Because my Cipher text output is Base 64. I tried to make the IV as unified as possible, in other words to look as if it is part of the Cipher text output.

So my first question would be how likely will the function below repeat itself. I did create a test app that has a timer on and looped the function below adding it to a database and checking if it repeats. The test app ran over night with a total of 69369 loops and no repeats.

```
// Generate a  16 bytes = 128 bits Initialization vector Used for AES-256
Function TfrmMain.GenerateIV:String;
  Var
   i,j : Integer;

   Const
    {Uppercase}
    alpa_L : array[1..26] of string = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k',
                                       'l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v',
                                       'w','x','y','z');
    {Lowercase}
    alpa_U : array[1..26] of string = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K',
                                       'L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V',
                                       'W','X','Y','Z');
    {numeric}
    Num : array[1..10] of string     = ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
Begin
  Result := '';
  Randomize;
  for i := 1 to 16 do //16 bytes = 128 bits AES=Fixed 128 Blocks
   Begin
      j := RandomRange(1, 4); //RandomRange - Delphi's help says inclusive but it is non-inclusive
      case j of
        1: Result := Result + alpa_L[RandomRange(1, 27)]; {alphabetic Uppercase}
        2: Result := Result + alpa_U[RandomRange(1, 27)]; {alphabetic Lowercase}
        3: Result := Result + Num[RandomRange(1, 11)]     {numeric}
      end;
   end;        
end;
```

Having said all of that, I have another idea that I'm trying to put together. My idea is as follows instead of hard coding the main encryption key into the executable. My server will randomly generate an encryption key and pass it unprotected to my application. All communication between the server and the app will be encrypted using this key for that session and once all the files have been downloaded the session is closed.

The only problem with the above is that because the encryption key is sent to the application unprotected for that session it will be possible with a bit of savvy to see what the app and server are communicating and the Hacker could see how authentication is done. Once he/she knows this the application could be redirected to their server to do the authentication part and then proceed on as usual. Only way to get around this is by protecting this key but then I'm back to square one "hard coded into the executable file"

So my first version of this application will be to hard code the key into the executable until I have solved the problem above.

Unfortunately the server does not support (HTTPS) Protocol

Answer (score 1):

You have no secure communication if the encryption key is embedded into the executable and changed once a year. There are secure key exchange protocols (i.e. look for Diffie-Hellman) which will let you exchange a session key securely. Of course you'd need to ensure you're talking to whom you're supposed to talk (and not to the man-in-the-middle) thereby you may also need to authenticate endpoints.

And even if the server does not support HTTPS, you can use the same techniques yorself over plain HTTP (or any other protocol). SSL is in no way tied to HTTP. You just need to write more code than simply relying on the web server doing all the "dirty work" for you.

Answer (score 1):

*Regarding repeatability of function*

The answer is that, while it is extremely unlikely, eventually it may be possible that the function repeats itself.

The reason for it is the way the random numbers are generated. Most compilers,including Delphi's one, use pseudo-random number generators. These generators use algorithms which generate the pseudo-random numbers based on a given initial value known as *seed*.

If you would know both the seed and the algorithm used, it would be possible to replicate the numbers generated. While the algorithm may be easy to know, the seed is not. In Delphi you establish the seed by using Randomize, which calls GetTickCount or QueryPerformanceCounter.

Given your code I think it is very unlikely that you ever see it happen, though I can not give you any proof on it. You can find more information on this matter [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#.22True.22_random_numbers_vs._pseudorandom_numbers).

*Regarding key communication*

Your best bet is to use what @Mad Hatter suggested. A good security schema for this type of environments is the following:

1. Use asymmetric cryptography to establish the encryption key which server and end user will use for communication. Best option here would be to go for [public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). Some examples of this are RSA and Diffie-Hellman.
2. Then use the generated key which only server and end user know as encryption key for AES or whatever [symmetric cryptography algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_cryptography) you prefer.

Theoretically speaking you could simply use asymmetrich cryptography for the whole communication, but it has higher overhead (computation costs) than the symmetric version, so I would suggest to use the schema explained above.

HTH